# How to disable Apple Radio in iTunes and iOS?

Tags: ios, itunes, apple-music, music.app, itunes-radio

> **Update:** iTunes/Apple Radio is now a paid service only — making it's
>   removal from clogging up our screens more relevant.

On an iPhone, it's possible to disable Apple Music from cluttering your Music.app if you're not looking to use Apple's subscription service.

Same goes for iTunes on the Mac.

But Apple Radio still remains visible. **How can I remove Apple Radio from showing?**

[image: Apple Radio takes up space on iPhone]
[image: Apple Radio forced on us in iTunes for Mac]

If you click to play, none of those radio stations work without an Apple Music subscription:
[image: Apple Radio only works if you pay Apple monthly]

---

### What I've tried in OS X:

[image: Disabling "Show Apple Music" in iTunes]
[image: And using parental preferences does nothing either]

---

### What I've tried in iOS:

> Settings.app > Music > disable "Show Apple Music"

[image: Apple Music settings]

---

> Settings.app > General > Restrictions > disable "Apple Music Connect"

[image: iOS restrictions]

Comment: Something's not right, I listen to an iTunes Radio station all the time and I'm not subscribed to Apple Music. Do any iTunes Radio stations work on your Mac or iPhone without an Apple Music subscription?

Comment: @RedEagle2000, I see — only the Beats one works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the answer is:

There's no way to disable Apple Radio from taking up space in iTunes and Music on iOS.

If this also bothers you, you can submit a report here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/

Or, specifically, here: http://www.apple.com/feedback/apple-music.html

Answer (score 2):

I have found a workaround in that using another app to play the music you have from Apple Music / Music.app bypasses all streaming.

- [Cesium Music Player](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cesium-streamlined-music-player/id924491991?mt=8) by Mike Clay

The interface is refined / simpler visually than Apple's new interface and it lets you control a bit more of the UI than Apple's app does. I find myself using it to only play songs that are local to iOS on long roadtrips to avoid a large download bill and stuttering when I am out of data coverage.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to disable it completely with this Flex patch:

http://getflex.co/patch/Disble-radio-completely-iOS-10.2/app/Music/id/36058

To do so, you need to first jailbreak your iOS device:
https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/